# What is open jdk in android studio

Tags: android-studio, java

open jdk hogging my ram what is it i have android studio 3.0.1 , i already installed Java `JDK`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk). A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2 and higher.

- Open your project in Android Studio and select **File > Project
  Structure** in the menu bar.
- In the **SDK Location** page and under **JDK location**, deselect the **Use embedded JDK** checkbox.
- Select the location of your **Java JDK**.
- Click OK.